# I deleted a branch locally but it keeps coming back (autocomplete issue)

Tags: bash, git, zsh, git-branch, oh-my-zsh

This has happened about three times already and is becoming a problem. I had a branch called say `branch_with_detailed_feature_description` and then for some reason, something got too messy and I wanted to start something on a branch forked more cleanly from develop, created a branch called `branch_with_detailed_feature_description_new` and deleted the old one with

`git branch -d branch_with_detailed_feature_description`

So in a rush to check out a branch typed

```
git checkout branch_with
```

pressed tab then enter and got on with coding. Later noticed it had autocompleted the deleted branch instead of the live one and brought it back to life. Is there a way to stop this behaviour so it doesn't keep happening? Is bad for productivity and will lead to an error sooner or later.

Comment: Actually this behaviour is really weird. I just tried to reproduce that, but when I delete the branch, it's removed also from autocomplete feature. Anyway, you might just need to put extra attention here and always check whether you're on `_new` branch.

Comment: Ok, thanks for testing it.. I normally use pure Linux, without any installed `zsh` like on this Mac but also wouldn't not know if the problem is pure git related or is affected by which terminal you have.

Comment: Thanks, the main question fixed it. I had already deleted it remotely on GitHub with the web interface, but `git branch -a` showed it was still hanging around locally, `git fetch --prune origin` made it go away, autocomplete now only suggests the new branch.